# how to break content within div tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to give break within div in html but i didn't get the solution please help me to find the solution
here is my html code

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-9">

                  <h5>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Apartments</h5>
                  <hr>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0258.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8050.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0516.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8055.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0344.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8062.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_7784.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8073.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0501.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8082.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0213.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8104.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0334.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8393.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0466.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8473.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0406.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8498.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0329.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0138.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_7890.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0128.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0295.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0123.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0295.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0068.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                  <br/>
                        <h5>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Testimonials</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
               </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

i want h5 tag in next line but when i load the page then it show to the next of the images

```
<h5>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Testimonials</h5>
```

please help me to find the solution

Comment: read carefully about bootstrap grid classes before applying them, every `.col-*-*` must be inside `row` or `container`

Comment: so what is the problem ..how i solve this problem i want break

Comment: also by default all heading tags h1... h6 are block elements, which means they will always be rendered on new line unless a extenally css like bootstrap grid class `col-*` in your case is making `h5` to be displayed as inline.

Comment: Specifically, read the [section about nesting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting).

Answer (score 2):

Wrap all your `col-* divs` inside a `div` with `class - row`. Also you can make use of class `text-center` `class` available in `twitter bootstrap` framework instead of adding `&nbsp;` to `h5`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-9">

        <h5 class="text-center">Apartments</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0258.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8050.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0516.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8055.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0344.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8062.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_7784.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8073.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0501.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8082.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0213.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8104.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0334.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8393.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0466.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8473.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0406.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8498.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0329.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0138.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_7890.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0128.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0295.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0123.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0295.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0068.jpg');?>"></a>
          </div>
          <br/>
        </div>
        <h5 class="text-center">Testimonials</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap need another class row after col-md-12 before col-md-9 or better remove the div with class col-md-12 because is useless.

Comment: If you see the code he has `col-md-3` after `col-md-9`. May be OP has something to do with `col-md-12`  and then with 3 and 9.. So its good to give what OP wants instead of altering his original design, unless we know its for good.. :) @GermanoPlebani

Comment: @nushrat.. anytime.. happy coding.. :) Do accept the answer if it was useful.. :)

Comment: No nushrat.. You've upvoted if am not wrong.. You need to tick right mark below vote count, to the left of the answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is put the images div in class row div and then provide the 
Example

HTML CODE

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-9">

        <h5>Apartments</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0258.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8050.jpg');?>"></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0516.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8055.jpg');?>"></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0344.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8062.jpg');?>"></a></div>
          <br/>
        </div>
        <h5>Testimonials</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is that you enclose the images in a row class and the h5 in a another row class.

This is create 2 rows inside class `col-md-9`,as shown below.

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="row">
                <h5>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Apartments</h5>
                <hr>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0258.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8050.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0516.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8055.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0344.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8062.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_7784.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8073.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0501.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8082.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0213.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8104.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0334.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8393.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0466.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8473.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0406.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_8498.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0329.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0138.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_7890.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0128.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0295.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0123.jpg');?>"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amen_LALCO_0295.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/gallery/LALCO_0068.jpg');?>"></a></div>

             </div>
             <div class="row">
                    <h5>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Testimonials</h5>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
           </div>
```